# Moq.Mock<IFoo>.Mock(...,...) is inaccessible due to its protection level error

Tags: unit-testing, moq

In Moq you start by writing some line that goes like this

```
var mock = Mock<IFoo>();
```

Then you continue on mocking except for me because I'm getting:

> 'Moq.Mock<IMyInterface>.Mock(Moq.MockBehavior, params object[])' is
>   inaccessible due to its protection level.

What am I messing up?

Comment: Is your interface not `public`?

Comment: Was missing the `public`. >.< Thanks.